# Properties of non-abelian characters

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

I'm looking for some (short of) non-abelian generalization of the following result:

> Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and let $f$ be a function on $G$
>   with values in some field of characteristic $0$. If $\sum_\sigma 
>  f(\sigma)=0$, then:
>
> $$\det(f(\sigma \tau^{-1}))_{\sigma, \tau \neq
>  1}=\frac{1}{|G|}\prod_{\chi \neq 1} \sum_{\sigma \in G} \chi (\sigma)
>  f (\sigma)$$

What can we say if $G$ in non-abelian (but still finite), under the same conditions?